# Windows Shell Desktop Preview

Tags: windows, shell, desktop

I've installed Rainmeter with Honeycomb and want only a simple Icon, which will act like the Windows "Show Desktop" Button in the right corner.

Well so far so good, I've got it working, that when I click on the Icon my Desktop will show up and the rest will be minimized:

```
...
LeftMouseUpAction=["shell:::{3080F90D-D7AD-11D9-BD98-0000947B0257}"]
...
```

Well now I want that when I hover over it, the preview will be shown:

```
MouseOverAction=[" Insert Magic --> Here <-- "]
```

Well this is my Problem, if anybody knows which Shell Command this is, or how it could be achieved, pls share your ideas with me.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be a good way, but you can do this:

1. Open up the folder where the ini file of the skin is.
2. Right click anywhere on the blank portion of the window and select New>Shortcut.
3. A dialog box will appear, asking you to locate the file the shortcut should point to.
4. Inside the text box, paste this:

C:\Windows\explorer.exe shell:::{3080F90D-D7AD-11D9-BD98-0000947B0257}

5. Click next. The dialog box will ask you to put a name for the shortcut. Put any name you like and press Finish to create the shortcut.
6. Replace the LeftMouseUpAction line with this:

LeftMouseUpAction=!Execute ["#CURRENTPATH#**"name of your shortcut"**.lnk"]

For example, if your shortcut's name is launch, then the line should be

LeftMouseUpAction=!Execute ["#CURRENTPATH#launch.lnk"]

7. You're good to go!